# Is posible open a "instance" component in BottomSheet (angular material 4/5/6)

Tags: angular, angular-material2, bottom-sheet

The current implementation of BottomSheetComponent in your "open" method, only allow Component or TemplateRef. 
The problem is, if your have a previous instance of component and insert this in a **BottomSheetComponet**, this, is not posible. Because, the **BottomSheetComponet** create a new instance of your content.

There is some way to make possible the visualization of a previous instance of some component, in a BottomSheet?

My actual config is:

- "@angular/animations": "^5.2.8",
- **"@angular/cdk": "^6.0.0-beta.4",**
- "@angular/common": "^5.2.8",
- "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.8",
- "@angular/core": "^5.2.8",
- "@angular/flex-layout": "^5.0.0-beta.13",
- "@angular/forms": "^5.2.8",
- "@angular/http": "^5.2.8",
- **"@angular/material": "^6.0.0-beta.4",**
- "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.8",
- "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.8",
- "@angular/router": "^5.2.8",
- ...
- ...

Comment: Hi, I am a bit unclear as to what you're actual question is. `There is some way to make possible the visualization of a previous instance of some component?` Are you asking if after an instance of a component is destroyed, can you go back after it has been destroyed, and get the exact same instance of that component?

Comment: Hi, the question points to: using a previous instance of a component (with its state) in a material component bottomsheet.

In the BottomSheet component API, the open method always creates a new instance of the component (content) to be displayed.

I would like to know if there is any way to visualize a component already instantiated.

Comment: `6.0.0-beta.4` requires Angular 6 beta

Comment: @Edric that is not a problem

Comment: I know I'm far too late, but have you managed to find a convenient way?